# Error pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, python-3.8

Símbolo del sistema arroja un error tras ejecutar la orden `pyinstaller` Escritor con interfaz grafica.py
ésto arroja:

```
C:\Users\Marcelo\Desktop\progra\python\leocontreras>pyinstaller Escritor con interfaz grafica.py
109 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.6
109 INFO: Python: 3.8.3rc1
109 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\marcelo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\marcelo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Marcelo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\marcelo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 112, in run
    spec_file = run_makespec(**vars(args))
  File "c:\users\marcelo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 58, in run_makespec
    spec_file = PyInstaller.building.makespec.main(filenames, **opts)
  File "c:\users\marcelo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\makespec.py", line 391, in main
    scripts = [make_path_spec_relative(x, specpath) for x in scripts]
  File "c:\users\marcelo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\makespec.py", line 391, in <listcomp>
    scripts = [make_path_spec_relative(x, specpath) for x in scripts]
  File "c:\users\marcelo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\makespec.py", line 53, in make_path_spec_relative
    filename = os.path.relpath(filename, start=spec_dir)
  File "c:\users\marcelo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\ntpath.py", line 703, in relpath
    raise ValueError("path is on mount %r, start on mount %r" % (
ValueError: path is on mount '\\\\.\\con', start on mount 'C:'**
```

¿Cómo puedo resolver ésto?

Comment: ¿El nombre real de tu módulo es `Escritor con interfaz grafica.py`? Si es así prueba con `pyinstaller "Escritor con interfaz grafica.py"` de cualquier forma no deberías usar espacios en el nombre del módulo, en todo caso deberías llamarlo `Escritor_con_interfaz grafica.py`

Answer (score 1):

Tiene que escapar los espacios con '\'.

Por ejemplo, si usa `pyinstaller Escritor\ con\ interfaz\ grafica.py` se debe terminar sin problemas.

Se puede ver [acá](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/ntpath.py#L697) que está intentando a resolucionar el path pero la falta de secuencias de escapa está causando el error.